# square brackets subsetting gives NAs

Tags: r, subset, states

I am subsetting states data frame. I want the the rows which have "spit" in column subregion. But it gives me all NAs. Where am I going wrong ?

I eventually want to add another column like this

```
states$code[states$subregion=="spit"]="Priority1"
```

Example code:

```
states=map_data("state")
states[states$subregion=="spit",]
# long lat group order region subregion
# NA     NA  NA    NA    NA   <NA>      <NA>
# NA.1   NA  NA    NA    NA   <NA>      <NA>
# NA.2   NA  NA    NA    NA   <NA>      <NA>
# NA.3   NA  NA    NA    NA   <NA>      <NA>
# NA.4   NA  NA    NA    NA   <NA>      <NA>
# NA.5   NA  NA    NA    NA   <NA>      <NA>
```

but this gives me correct results `states[states$region=="north carolina",]`

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at the structure of `states` and specifically note that there are `NA` values in `subregion`.  If you subset using square brackets like you're doing, `NA` is *included* in the subset.  A small example:

```
dat <- data.frame(x=1:10, y=c('a', 'b'), z='foo')
dat$y[9:10] <- NA

dat[dat$y == 'a',]

      x    y    z
1     1    a  foo
3     3    a  foo
5     5    a  foo
7     7    a  foo
NA   NA <NA> <NA>
NA.1 NA <NA> <NA>
```

If you use `na.omit` or something similar, you'll see the results you're expecting:

```
foo <- states[states$subregion=="spit",]
foo[!is.na(foo$subregion),]

#            long      lat group order         region subregion
# 10321 -76.00285 36.55471    40 10321 north carolina      spit
# 10322 -75.93983 36.55471    40 10322 north carolina      spit
# 10323 -75.92837 36.54898    40 10323 north carolina      spit
# 10324 -75.91691 36.52606    40 10324 north carolina      spit
# 10325 -75.91118 36.50887    40 10325 north carolina      spit
# 10326 -75.91118 36.49168    40 10326 north carolina      spit
# 10327 -75.93983 36.49168    40 10327 north carolina      spit
# 10328 -75.96848 36.49741    40 10328 north carolina      spit
# 10329 -75.97421 36.50314    40 10329 north carolina      spit
# 10330 -75.97421 36.52606    40 10330 north carolina      spit
# 10331 -75.98566 36.55471    40 10331 north carolina      spit
# 10332 -76.00285 36.55471    40 10332 north carolina      spit
```

Or in one line:

```
states[states$subregion == 'spit' & !is.na(states$subregion),]
```

Comment: `long      lat     group  order      region subregion`
`2391  -81.29125 31.41528    10  2391        georgia      <NA>`
`6081  -70.10712 42.02073    21  6081  massachusetts      main`
`13460 -73.41881 44.13494    52 13460        vermont      <NA>`
I am getting something like this if I use na.omit

Comment: see my edit.  Instead, subset normally and just don't show the rows with `NA` in `subregion`.

Comment: My previous `na.omit` comment was wrong. This does work, though: `states[which(states$subregion == "spit"),]`. Switching from logical to index indexing circumvents the `NA`'s.

Comment: @BrianDiggs correct!  I spaced on that too.  however, I don't like the syntax difference versus my edit.  Its more code, but clearer that I have taken care of `NA` values also.